# Why do I get the default "welcome aboard" screen when I try to deploy with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app works locally, but when I try to deploy to Heroku I'm getting the "welcome aboard: you're riding ruby on rails!" screen.

So far I have:

- removed public/index.html and set a new root path in the config/routes file.
- tried running rails s --environment production to see if it was the production environment configuration that was the problem, but that works too.
- run "heroku run rake db:migrate

What am I missing? The logs look normal and aren't giving me any obvious error messages... please let me know what other information would be useful for me to provided, I'm totally lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that it failed to delete from your git repo

run git status and see if deleted public/index.html shows

If yes then run

```
 git rm public/index.html 
 git commit -m "Removed public/index.html"
```

Then push it to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```